# Show that $A^T=A$ for all $A\in S$ if and only if $S$ is abelian where $S$ is the subgroup generated by $B^T=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.
Let $S$ be a subset of $GL_n(F)$ such that every $B \in S$ satises $B^T = B$, and let
$\langle S \rangle \le GL_n(F)$ be the subgroup generated by $S$. Show that $A^T = A$ for all $A \in S$ if and only if $S$ is abelian.

I'm a bit confused as to what the problem here is? Isn't it true by the definition of what $S$ is? What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up $S$ and $\langle S\rangle$. Is it supposed to be "Show that $A^T = A$ for all $A \in \langle S\rangle$ if and only if $\langle S\rangle$ is abelian"?

Comment: My guess is you want 'show that $A^T=A$ for all $A\in \langle S\rangle$ iff $\langle S\rangle$ is abelian'. So you know the generators are self-transpose, and the question asks to show that two self-transpose matrices commute iff they generate a sugbroup of self-transpose matrices.

Comment: Hint: If $C^T=C$ and $D^T=D$, then $(CD)^T = D^TC^T = DC$, so...